# Open a QFileDialog over a QQuickItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I want to open a QFileDialog over a QQuickItem.

```
 void
 MyCoolQQuickItem::loadFileDialog()
 {
   QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open a file", 
                      "C:\\path to my stuff\\", "*.*");
   if(filename.size()>0) {
     // load file and do stuff
   }
 }
```

My MyCoolQQuickItem is a Subclass of QQuickItem.
And QFileDialog::getOpenFileName need a QWidget* as parent. If I pass a null_ptr instead, the dialog opens correctly as modal dialog. But after I close the dialog the wrong window gets the focus.

I tried to pass the window instead(this->window(), but I have a QQuickWindow, what also could not be parsed in a QWidget.

I could use the QML File-Dialog instead.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html

But I want to use a QFileDialog here.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledialog.html

Any Idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the QML version, it is absolutely the same dialog you will get from the `QWidget` based dialog. The only thing you will gain from using a `QWidget` based dialog is you will make it backward and you will drag several MBs for the `Qt5Widgets` library.

Whatever you think you might be gaining from wanting to do that, it will not be worthy the effort to do it. The old QtQuick1 offered a proxy component to show widgets in QML, but this is not available with QtQuick2, because it has a different approach towards rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with saving space with not adding Qt5Widgets you have a good point.
I just want to be able to use the good old dialogs and started adding this QFileDialog without thinking doing it in QML.
I'll try it.